# Converting .map() from JavaScript API to Python API?

Tags: python, javascript, google-earth-engine

I wrote this code using the Earth Engine JavaScript API. The code clips the image collection using variable "table," which is a feature collection of about 12,000 points. I get the length of the image collection and use that number to create a a variable "sequence." I use this variable to create a nested map loop of sorts. I grab a single image and get a list of coordinates from that image. Then for each set of coordinates in the list, I store a bunch of information from that point into a dictionary and create a feature out of it. I need to convert this code to Python, but I am not sure how to convert the lines of code that use the map() function twice ("var getImgCoords and var getMetadata"). The variable "sequence2" changes for each loop, so I thought I could use the iterate() function instead of map().

```
var TerraClimate = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE"),
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/adrianom/CAN_AK_Coordinates")

var SearchArea = table;
var SearchAreaGeom = SearchArea.geometry();
var terraclimate_bounds = TerraClimate.filterBounds(SearchAreaGeom);

  // Clip collection to search area, more precisely than filterBounds above.
  var icClip = terraclimate_bounds.map(function(img){
    var i = img.clip(SearchAreaGeom);
    return(i);
  });

  var icClip_len = icClip.size();
  var col_list = icClip.toList(icClip_len);


  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, icClip_len.subtract(1));


  var getImgCoords = sequence.map(function(i){
    var img = ee.Image(col_list.get(i));
    var coords = img.geometry().coordinates();
    var coords_len = coords.size();
    var sequence2 = ee.List.sequence(0, coords_len.subtract(1));

    var getMetadata = sequence2.map(function(j){
        var coor = coords.get(j);
        var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(coor);
        var reduce = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geom, 4638.312116386398);

        var dictionary = ee.Dictionary({
          x: ee.List(coor).get(0),
          y: ee.List(coor).get(1),
          Start_Date: ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')),
          End_Date: ee.Date(img.get('system:time_end'))
        });

        var combine_dict = reduce.combine(dictionary);
        var feature = ee.Feature(geom, combine_dict);
        return(feature);
    });


    return(getMetadata);

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, since you shouldn't need to change anything to migrate from JS to Python, but in this case where you have a nested loop you have to do some workaround. No need to change the logic, just the structure.

```python
import ee
ee.Initialize()

TerraClimate = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE")
table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/adrianom/CAN_AK_Coordinates")

SearchArea = table
SearchAreaGeom = SearchArea.geometry()
terraclimate_bounds = TerraClimate.filterBounds(SearchAreaGeom)

# Clip collection to search area, more precisely than filterBounds above.
icClip = terraclimate_bounds.map(lambda img: img.clip(SearchAreaGeom))

icClip_len = icClip.size()
col_list = icClip.toList(icClip_len)
sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, icClip_len.subtract(1))

# make a function that takes coords and img and return a function
def getMetadata(coords, img):
    # I changed coords because did not work as you have it in JS
    coords = ee.List(ee.List(coords).get(0))
    img = ee.Image(img)
    def wrap(j):
        coor = ee.List(coords.get(j))
        geom = ee.Geometry.Point(coor)
        reduce = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geom, 4638.312116386398)

        dictionary = ee.Dictionary({
          'x': ee.List(coor).get(0),
          'y': ee.List(coor).get(1),
          'Start_Date': ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')),
          'End_Date': ee.Date(img.get('system:time_end'))
        })

        combine_dict = reduce.combine(dictionary)
        feature = ee.Feature(geom, combine_dict)
        return feature
        return coor
    return wrap

# function to loop over image indexes
def getImgCoords(i):
    img = ee.Image(col_list.get(i))
    coords = img.geometry().coordinates()
    coords_len = coords.size()
    sequence2 = ee.List.sequence(0, coords_len.subtract(1))
    # the function getMetadata returns a function, so map it
    return sequence2.map(getMetadata(coords, img))

# final result
imgCoords = sequence.map(getImgCoords)
```

By the way, you don't need to map over a list of indexes and get the elements from the list with the given index.. the `map` function goes over each element of the list, so you should just use it that way. In `getImgCoords` just map over `coords` and instead o mapping over `sequence` you could just map over `col_list`. But I translated the code as it was.